# Read Only Integration Token

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm looking to setup an integration token for the REST API. I understand the process for this, as well as the ability to specify the tokens access to different resources such as products or customers. What I am unsure about is how to only allow read access to one of these tokens. I do not want this integration to be able to create, change, or delete data. Is this possible using Magento's built in REST API?